# MySQL indirect ON DELETE CASCADE for 1:1 relationship

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a super-type entity and its sub-type, there is one to one relationship, and the `ON DELETE` is set to `CASCADE` (so when the super-type is deleted, its sub-type is deleted also). The sub-type also has relationship with some other, non-related entity - this relationship also has `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

```
super_type
  id

sub_type
  id
  super_type_id   ON DELETE CASCADE  # references super_type.id
  other_table_id  ON DELETE CASCADE  # references other_table.id
```

When some record from `other_table` gets deleted, so does the corresponding `sub_type` record. But this leaves a `super_type` record that has no `sub_type` attached. How can I prevent this?

*Note: I can't make "double-linked relationship" (adding a foreign key to `super_type` referencing to `sub_type`), because there are more than one sub-type.*

Comment: So you want to delete a super-type, because a sub-type was deleted by cascading the deletion of a other_table entry. Hmm... what if there are more sub-types for that super-type? They should all get removed, right?

Comment: "When some record from other_table gets deleted, so does the corresponding sub_type record. But this leaves a super_type record that has no sub_type attached. "  that's logical that, that super_type record still exists within the table.."How can I prevent this?" have a feeling you need to check MySQL's triggers to solve this.

Comment: @RaymondNijland probably, although the OP is on mysql, which has a really annoying habit of not running triggers on deletions that are caused by referral integrity checks.

Comment: @luksch "what if there are more sub-types for that super-type?" There are not. It's a one to one relationship.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký then I do not understand your note: "I can't make "double-linked relationship" (adding a foreign key to super_type referencing to sub_type), because there are more than one sub-type.". But of course you di state that it is a one-to-one relationship. Can you elaborate what your note means then?

Comment: @luksch Sorry for the confusion. I mean that there can exist many different sub-type entities (tables). But always only one is attached to the super-type. Because of this, it is impossible to create a foreign key on the super-type table, because it would have to reference to many different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with triggers. Unfortunately not easily, since mysql has the very annoying "feature" of not running triggers if a row gets deleted by cascading referential integrity checks, i.e. in your case.

What I did in the past to avoid this problem was to remove the cascading deletions in the table description. Instead have triggers on deletion of any row in super_type, sub_type and other_table that delete:

super-type
  - trigger **BEFORE** DELETE to delete the sub-type entries

sub-type
  - trigger **AFTER** DELETE to delete the super-type

other-table
  - trigger **AFTER** DELETE to delete any sub-type that references it.

Here a link to the msql-behavior feature/bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61555

Comment: Sometimes it is better to write App code instead of Triggers/FKs.

Comment: @RickJames Indeed - if access to the table is limited to very few applications and their actions on the table are managed by well written DAOs, then it may make good sense to put the referential integrity checks into the DAO layer.